# Radio buttons on a React component take an extra click to be marked

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, radio-button, jsx

I have a very simple react functional component, with a div with some inputs of type radio.
Just like this:

```
const radioHandler = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log(event.target.value);
}

return(
   <div className="radioDiv" onChange={radioHandler}>
      <label>My label:</label>
      <input type="radio" value="1" name="group_x" checked/> One
      <input type="radio" value="2" name="group_x"/> Two
      <input type="radio" value="3" name="group_x"/> Three
   </div>
);
```

Looks very simple, like this:
[image: how it looks]

What happens is, the option number 1 is checked by default, as desired. But when I click the others, it takes an extra click to actually change to the one I'm trying to check. I've added an ´´´preventDefault()´´´ method because without it, I would click option 2, and then option 3, and it would jump to the default checked one, and not the 3. But with the `preventDefault` it takes an extra click to make the blue dot actually go to the desired option. Why is this? How can I make it work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:
basically remove the preventDefault behaviour and defaultChecked instead of checked.

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const radioHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="radioDiv" onChange={radioHandler}>
      <label>My label:</label>
      <input type="radio" value="1" name="group_x" defaultChecked /> One
      <input type="radio" value="2" name="group_x" /> Two
      <input type="radio" value="3" name="group_x" /> Three
    </div>
  );
}
```